# Topological property of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've been working on Görtz and Torsten's book (by myself, not from class) and have come across problem that makes me worry I'm missing some fundamental technical understanding.

Prove: Let $Y$ be an irreducible scheme with generic point $\eta$ and let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Then the map $Z\mapsto f^{-1}(\eta)\cap Z$ is a bijective map from the set of irreducible components of $X$ meeting $f^{-1}(\eta)$ onto the set of irreducible components of $f^{-1}(\eta)$, and the generic point of $Z$ is the generic point of $f^{-1}(\eta)\cap Z$.

Zeroth thing to check  for the last statement is that $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is a sober space.

Then first thing to check is that $f^{-1}(\eta)\cap Z$ is irreducible in $f^{-1}(\eta)$. Then check that every irreducible of $f^{-1}(\eta)$ extends to an irreducible of $X$ which is equivalent to showing its closure in $X$ is irreducible in $X$. Then the final statement follows if we can show the generic point of $Z$ lies in $f^{-1}(\eta)$ if $f^{-1}(\eta)\cap Z$ is nonempty.

The problem is that I don't even know how to think about $f^{-1}(\eta)$, as the singleton $\eta$ itself need not be closed nor open. It is contained in all open subsets of $Y$, but pullback maps the topology of $Y$ to only a subset of the topology of $X$. Perhaps I need some lemmas about sober spaces in general, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key idea you're missing is that since $f$ is continuous, it preserves the specialization order.  In particular, while $\{\eta\}$ is typically not open, it is always *specialization-open* (i.e., closed under generalization), and so $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is specialization-open as well.  Now suppose $Z$ is an irreducible closed subset of $X$ with generic point $z$.  The set $f^{-1}(\eta)\cap Z$ is specialization-open as a subset of $Z$, and so if it is nonempty it must contain the generic point $z$.

Comment: Thanks! I will investigate the concept more work on it.